# Grep command to find blank line - works in terminal, not in the file itself?

Tags: perl, parsing, grep

I am writing a perl script, called by qmail for each incoming mail, to parse the content and find the body of the email. The reason for doing so is to add some user information from a database, append that to the body, and forward to another address (a listserv).

Unsolveable problem is this:

```
cat dbody.txt|grep -A1000 '^\s*$'
```

Purpose: To find the first blank line (being the end of header information) and return all after that

When I run that line from the command line (using terminal) (ie. directly) - it works fine. Returns the body of the email.

When I run it in the script itself - **it doesn't**.

Have tested endlessly and cannot think of a reason as to why this would be, or what I should change. help!

Lines from the script - the first "test" - works fine.

```
$test =`cat dbody.txt|grep -A1000 '^\s*$'`;
$body= `cat dbody.txt|grep -A1000 '2,/^$/d'`;
```

When I print the above into the final email - $test returns the full text (as a test), $body remains blank.

Comment: I don't know how you manage to get that produce any result in Perl. Are you using the `system` function?

Comment: @perreal No, he just used the wrong markdown formatting so his backticks did not show.

Comment: If you have a message longer than 1000 lines, you will be truncating it. From your description, I gather this is not intentiional. (A base64 attachment larger than about 40KB would suffice to exceed the 1000 line boundary.)

Comment: It was intentional, these will only be short messages. Cheers though.

Comment: Only wondering when you tagged this question for `perl` why you don't use for example `Email::Simple` (http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Simple-2.100/lib/Email/Simple.pm) for the correct message parsing. (and headers modify too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Perl like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $body;
open my $file, "<", "dbody.txt" or die("$!");
while (<$file>) {
    $body .= $_ if defined $body;
    $body  = "" if not defined $body and /^$/;
}
close $file;
print $body;
```

or, escape the dollar signs:

```
$body= `grep -A1000 '2,/^\$/d' dbody.txt`;
```

Comment: Or to bypass the Perl double-quotish behavior, assign the script to a variable in single quotes, then interpolate the variable; `my $script = q(sed '1,/^$/d'); my $body = qx($script);` (... I'm using the generalized quoting mechanisms to aid readability and work around markup paucity, you might find other quoting mixes which work for you.)

Comment: Perfect - the second part, with the dollar sign escaped, works to fix the problem I described originally. A thousand thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The standard solution in `sed`:

```
sed '1,/^$/d' dbody.txt
```

In other words, delete through the first empty line.

Note that your regex was wrong, too, albeit harmless in practice. The separator line must not even contain any whitespace (but I don't think you will ever find a real-life email message with a whitespace-only header line).

Comment: Thanks for the responses, great. Appreciate the UUCA exemption. The sed option works too - thanks - but the initial problem remains: sed works from the command line, but NOT in the script itself. It just returns empty when processed. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2349186, you need to escape the dollar sign like `\$^`, perl thinks it's a variable.

Comment: How are you invoking the script? If `qmail` has its own quote interpretation and/or dollar substitution, that may be the source of all these problems. Storing the script in a separate shell script should allow you to work around any such issues.

Comment: Ah, or Perl script, yes! Now I get it. @perreal's diagnostic is spot on; it's Perl, not Qmail, doing its own quote interpretation and variable substitution.

Comment: Agreed - that fixes the problem I had. @perreal and triplee thank you so much for your time.